# Can anyone help me with generalizing this equation for counting permutations of indistinguishable numbers?

Tags: summation, permutations

I don't think it's necessary to go into the details of why, but I am working on a code that generates lists of size $n$ with integer values that can range between $0$ and some value $m$. The important thing is the order of the values within the list doesn't matter, and I don't want any equivalent lists to be included twice. An example of such a set of lists $(n=3, m=2)$ is: [0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,1,1],[0,1,2],[0,2,2],[1,1,1], etc. You can think of it as counting in base $m$ except no value can be larger than any value left of it. This way I ensure no list gets counted more than once.

In order to generate these lists, I use nested for loops, where the inner for loop starts at the current value of it's parent for loop (Python code):
`for h in range(n+1): for i in range(h, n+1): for j in range(i, n+1): mylist = [h,i,j]`

The problem I have now is figuring out the index $z$ of list (e.g. [h,i,j]) given the list itself. In the above example, for [0,0,0] $z=0$, for [0,0,1] $z=1$ etc. For $m=3$, I know the equation for $z$ looks like $$z=\sum_{a=0}^{h-1} \sum_{b=a}^{n} \sum_{c=b}^{n} 1 + \sum_{a=h}^{i-1} \sum_{b=a}^{n} 1 + \sum_{a=i}^{j-1} 1$$ for some set [h, i, j]. Plugging this into Wolfram Alpha, I can get it simplified to $$\frac{h^3}{6}-\frac{h^2 n}{2}-\frac{h^2}{2}+\frac{hn^2}{2}+hn+\frac{h}{3}+j-\frac{i^2}{2}+{in}+\frac{i}{2}$$
which is much quicker to compute. However, I need to be able to use ostensibly any value of $m$, but so far I am struggling to find a general equation for $z$. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PS: I know there are other ways to generate these lists like this (a few of which I've played around with before), but for reasons that I don't think are worth getting into, this ordering is the most preferable for my application.

Comment: I don't understand your list example. You have [1,0,0] and [0,0,1]. Could you please explain more clearly how this list is constructed?

Comment: Presumably $[1, 0, 0]$ is a typo and it's meant to be $[1, 1, 1]$?

Comment: I think OP should clarify the question otherwise we have to play guessing games.

Comment: Sorry, JBL is correct, the [1,0,0] was indeed a typo and should be [1,1,1]. I have edited the question to reflect this.